# Mongodb check if connection is ok via Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.2 and MongoDB 3.2.

I want to test if connection with is ok before my app starts (i can't use DB facade), in the monolog configuration. If connection is not ok, i will use logging in file.

By recommendation, i'm testing MongoClient, Mongo and MongoDB\Client, and using whatever is enabled.

I'm trying to test mongo connect as the following:

```
$mongoClient = new \MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$mongoClient->selectCollection('mydb', 'mycollection');
```

That's the return:

```
Client {   
    +manager: Manager {#21}
    +uri: "mongodb://localhost:27017"   
    +typeMap: [
        array => "MongoDB\Model\BSONArray",
        document => "MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument",
        root => "MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument"   
    ]
}
```

Finnaly, my questions:

- Exists a way to use DB facade before app starts?
- How and what is the right way to test MongoDB connection with PHP?

If you has another suggestion, i will be thankful.

Comment: Finnaly i get the exception when fire: $mongoClient->mydb->mycollection->findOne(). This solve my problem, but my questions persist. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to PHP document, `the driver connects to the database lazily` (http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.getservers.php), the only way to test connection should be actually execute commands like `findOne()` stated in yours comment.

In addition, if the name of DB or Collection is uncertain at the point, you can use `listDatabases()` method which also throws exceptions if connection fails.

Answer (score 0):

using this way you can check MongoDB connection with PHP:

```
$connection = new MongoClient(); // connects to localhost:27017
$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://example.com" ); // connect to a remote host (default port: 27017)
$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://example.com:65432" ); // connect to a remote host at a given port
```

Comment: No, this will not trigger any errors or exceptions. (Remember I need to do something that works for the 3 classes I listed)